# Error: No flavor is associated with flavor dimension 'xxx'

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have the following in my application-level build.gradle file:

```
flavorDimensions "store", "features"

productFlavors {
    amazon {
        dimension "store"
        ...
    }
    play {
        dimension "store"
        ...
    }
    none {
        dimension "features"
        ...
    }
    myAwesomeFeature {
        dimension "features"
        ...
    }
    anotherAwesomeFeature {
        dimension "features"
        ...
    }
    all {
        dimension "features"
        ...
    }
}
```

I get an error when I try to sync my project files saying "Error: No flavor is associated with flavor dimension 'store'." I was previously using flavorDimension in the productFlavors but there were compiler warnings that it was deprecated for "dimension"... with either (or both) it throws the error.

I clearly have 2 flavors with dimension store. I've looked through docs and sample code and can't find out what's wrong. I tried updating my gradle plugin from 1.2.0 through 1.2.3 and I've tried upgrading my version of gradle from 2.2.1 to 2.4.

What am I doing wrong? I tried copying the example from [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants) and it gives a similar error. [This article](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts) was pretty worthless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason the build system does not like either "none" or "all" (not sure which, because I changed them both) as a product flavor. I changed them to noFeatures and allFeatures and it worked fine.

It's fine if there are reserved words... it would be awesome if they were prevalent in the documentation. AFAIK, all and none aren't reserved words in Java or Groovy.

It would have also been awesome if the error message was more meaningful.

Comment: Gradle doesn't seem to like `all`.

Comment: `all` is a reserved keyword for Gradle. It belongs to DomainObjectCollection Interface

Here is the reference - https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DomainObjectCollection.html#all-groovy.lang.Closure-